# How to respond to a click outside a certain area?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

My document looks like this:
[image]

Basically the background is one full-screen, transparent div. There are couple problems...if I just create the background div and don't apply any z-index to it, it ends up being on top of everything, and I cannot click on the box. If I set the z-index of the background div to be below the box, I can't seem to click on the background. What I want to do, it to be able to click both on the box, and the background.

```
var x = document.getElementById("bg");
x.addEventListener("click",reset,false);

function reset() {
   alert("reset was clicked");
}
```

CLARIFICATION: box is on the same node level as the bg. it is not inside the bg div.

Comment: So strange, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please.

Comment: If I click on the `#box` in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dj6GZ/) it functions as you desire. (Safari on OS X)

Comment: Is your `box` IN the `bg`? Is it outside? Post relevant markup, otherwise there are too many unknowns.

Comment: Mate you need to post your HTML Markup and all JavaScript you have that's not working, because it's really hard to tell what the issue is without knowing your code. How can you expect people to help you? Here is a jsfiddle that works and you can click both box and bg: http://jsfiddle.net/nDNKg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must post your code so every one can help you. My [test](http://jsfiddle.net/VzwFh/) work correctly on Firefox and Chrome. If I'm guessing right, the background in your code isn't expanded. Try to remove `html, body { width:100%; height:100%; }` in my example to see the problem.

On IE browser, you need to use a transparent gif image as background of the background div, otherwise the background div may be unable to receive mouse click event.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this jQuery plugin - even if it doesn't solve your particular question the code could provide insight into your dilemma.

[jQuery clickoutside](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/02/17/clickoutside-jquery-plugin/)